# Check occurence of space in same place

Tags: vb.net

I want restrict user to pass only digits, letters, -, and single space. Problem is I don't want to have a situation where the user can put more than one space in same place like below:

```
Something  45 Last    Ter
```

As you see we got two places where more than one space has been placed after "Something" and after "Last". How can I change my code to be secure that situation can't happen?

```
'check whether Symbol contains only letters, digits or -  symbol otherwise break                                                
For Each c As Char In txtNazwa.Text
    If Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) AndAlso c <> "-"c AndAlso c <> " " Then
        MessageBox.Show("Only letters, digits, - and single space are available", "Ostrzeżenie", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
         Exit Try
    End If
Next
```

Comment: you could use `String.Replace("  ", " ")` and fix it rather than bug them

Comment: the formatting eats it, but use 2 spaces for the first arg, 1 for the second and any multi spaces will be converted...`String.Replace([2 spaces], [1 space]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct answer to the question:

Check if the string contains 2 consecutive spaces like this:

```
If txtNazwa.Text.Contains("  ") Then
    MessageBox.Show("The value must not contain two consecutive spaces")
End If
```

If instead, you want to fix this for the user, you can do this:

```
Dim str As String = txtNazwa.Text

While str.Contains("  ")
    str = str.Replace("  ", " ")
End While

txtNazwa.Text = str
```

Comment: ok but what if he put 3 or 4 or more spaces? I did this way but then i would have to douplicate this method..

Comment: @StackUser, It will work too because 3 spaces contain 2 spaces

Answer (score 3):

I assume the user is typing into a text box. Look at the textbox change event.

```
private void currencyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      currencyTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(currencyTextBox.Text, " {2 }", " ")
   }
   catch
   {
      // Do something if we get an error
   }
}
```

Comment: nice idea to check as the user types

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex and keep the trouble to yourself.

```
Dim Nazwa_Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(txtNazwa.Text, "\s+", " ")
```

Next use your For-Loop as mentioned in your post.